# Replace my continue statement with different logic

Tags: javascript, eslint

```
    do {
        const randX = randomNumberBetween(0, 9);
        const randY = randomNumberBetween(0, 9);
        if ((randX === x1 && randY === y1) || (randX === x2 && randY === y2)) {
            continue;
        }
        matrix[randX][randY] = 'Obstacle';
        placedBlocks += 1;
    } while (placedBlocks < blocks);
    matrix[x1][y1] = 'Start';
    matrix[x2][y2] = 'Goal';
    return matrix;
}
```

I need to replace my `continue` statement with other logic because my ESLint rules don't allow me to use it.

My whole task is to create pathfinding algorithm through matrix with block fields, and everything is working. I just need to replace `continue;` with something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of skipping the loop in `if` condition, just invert the `if` condition and do the work inside `if` condition,

```
do {
    const randX = randomNumberBetween(0, 9);
    const randY = randomNumberBetween(0, 9);
    if (!((randX === x1 && randY === y1) || (randX === x2 && randY === y2))) {
        matrix[randX][randY] = 'Obstacle';
        placedBlocks += 1;
    }
} while (placedBlocks < blocks);
    matrix[x1][y1] = 'Start';
    matrix[x2][y2] = 'Goal';
    return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional currently checks whether the `randX` and `randY` coordinate pair overlaps one of two points. You can invert the logic in your code, moving the block that you're skipping with `continue` inside the `if`.

The inversion is to check whether `randX` and `randY` do *not* overlap one of two points, either by negating the previous conditional, or, much cleaner, flipping `===` to `!==` and `&&` to `||`:

```
do {
    const randX = randomNumberBetween(0, 9);
    const randY = randomNumberBetween(0, 9);

    if ((randX !== x1 || randY !== y1) && (randX !== x2 || randY !== y2)) {
        matrix[randX][randY] = 'Obstacle';
        placedBlocks += 1;
    }
} while (placedBlocks < blocks);

matrix[x1][y1] = 'Start';
matrix[x2][y2] = 'Goal';
return matrix;
```

Here's a working demonstration of logical equivalence:

```js
const valid = (randX, randY, x1, x2, y1, y2) => 
  (randX !== x1 || randY !== y1) && 
  (randX !== x2 || randY !== y2)
;

const valid2 = (randX, randY, x1, x2, y1, y2) => 
  !((randX === x1 && randY === y1) || 
    (randX === x2 && randY === y2))
;

console.log(
  [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
  ].map(e => valid(...e) === valid2(...e))
   .every(e => e)
);
```